# Projective subvarieties of blow-ups of affine varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, blow-ups

Let $X$ be an integral affine scheme of finite type over a field $k$. Let $Y\subset  X$ be an integral closed subscheme of codimension $n>0$. We blow up $X$ along $Y$ and get a $k$-scheme $X'$. Is it true that there is no closed immersion from a proper $k$-scheme of dimension $\geq n$ to $X'$?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not true. Take $X = \mathbb{A}^4$ and let 
$$
Y = \{x_1x_3 - x_2^2 = x_1x_4 - x_2x_3 = x_2x_4 - x_3^2 = 0 \} \subset X
$$
be the cone over a rational twisted cubic curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$. The codimension of $Y$ in $X$ is $n = 2$. On the other hand, it is easy to check that the fiber of the blowup $X' \to X$ over the origin (the vertex of the cone) is $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: what if we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are smooth?

Comment: Since $X$ is affine, any proper subvariety of $X'$ is contained in a fiber of the blow up, which has dimension $\leq n-1$ if $X$ and $Y$ are smooth.

Comment: @Aknazar Kazhymurat: No, I don't know any reference, in fact I don't know any example of what you mention — but I am not an expert.